# Get length of object array

Tags: javascript, json

In my Angular controller, the `$scope.print` variable has this value:

```
{
   "employees":
     [
         {
            "firstName":"John", 
            "lastName":"Doe"
         },
         {
            "firstName":"Anna", 
            "lastName":"Smith"
         }
     ]
}
```

**Question:**
Using JavaScript how do I to find its length?